# Can the iPad support multiple Regional Settings simultaneously?

Tags: keyboard, language, spelling

I need spell-checking in different languages such as English, German and Norwegian. I currently have only German spell-checking and it is quite irritating that it messes up with other languages' words. Is there some easy way of having spell-checking in multiple languages on the iPad?

What about keyboards? Is it possible to have many regional settings on one iPad, easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple keyboards enabled: `Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> International Keyboards`. Add whichever keyboards you wish. Then, when you are typing text, hit the globe key on the keyboard to switch between the different keyboards.

As far as I know, you can't have multiple languages enabled at the same time for spell checking. However, you can switch between them using `Settings -> International -> Language`.

Comment: Spell-checking is tied to the currently-selected keyboard so zwitching keyboard result in different language suggestions. Thank you, worked +1, aber `"Einstellungen > Allgemein > Tastatur > Internationale Tastaturen"` und `"Einstellungen > Landeseinstellungen >  Sprache"` ;)